# Merge 2 data.tables on multiple fuzzy matches

Tags: r

I have 2 data.tables that have irrelevant variable names in ambiguous order:

[image]

I want to merge dt1 and dt2. But in reality I want to join regardless of which column the information is in.

```
dt3=inner_join(dt1,dt2,by=c('Col1','Col2')) #Won't join all 4;only 2.
```

I cannot unite the columns as in reality there are many (>100) and they cannot reliably be ordered). Is there a way to combine these so all 4 observation will be joined?

```
> dput(dt1)
structure(list(Col1 = c("Todd", "Leroy", "Ham", "Tiffon"), Col2 = c("Sally", 
"Brown", "York", "Maude"), Y1 = c(687.4, 12.9, 34.6, 34.6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
> dput(dt2)
structure(list(Col1 = c("Sally", "Leroy", "York", "Tiffon"), 
    Col2 = c("Todd", "Brown", "Ham", "Maude"), Y1 = c(343.1, 
    5748.6, 942.5, 365.5)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Desired output (don't care how it outputs the Col1,Col2 variables):

[image]

Comment: So you want to join only by rowname (Obs1, Obs2, ...)? What would your desired output after joining look like?

Comment: Hopefully edited for clarity. Was poorly constructed initially

Comment: `dput` of your data has column names as row 1.

Comment: Fixed dputs and removed the internal self pointers (was causing problems for me)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if I understand your question right. But what about generating a sorted merging id. The mergeing id could be used.

```
dt1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("Obs1", "Obs2", "Obs3", "Obs500"), 
               V2 = c("Sally", "Leroy", "York", "Tiffon"), 
               V3 = c("Todd", "Brown", "Ham", "Maude")),row.names =  c(NA, -4L),
               class = c("data.frame"))  
dt1

dt2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("Obs1", "Obs2", "Obs3", "Obs500"), 
               V2 = c("Todd", "Leroy", "Ham", "Tiffon"), 
               V3 = c("Sally", "Brown", "York", "Maude")), row.names =  c(NA, -4L),
               class = c("data.frame"))
dt2

columns <- c("V2","V3")

order_paste <- function (x) {

  x_sorted <- sort(x)
  x_sorted_paste <- paste(x_sorted,collapse = "")
  return(x_sorted_paste)

}

dt1$merge_id <- apply(dt1[columns],1, order_paste)
dt2$merge_id <- apply(dt2[columns],1, order_paste)

dt3<-dplyr::inner_join(dt1,dt2,by=c('merge_id'))
```

Comment: Will not be possible to generate a merge id